# Running MPI program on windows. working fine on Linux but giving error on windows

Tags: mpi

I have program written in open MPI on linux where it is running fine, I complied it on windows but when i am running it using command mpirun -n 2 abc.exe, its showing error on receiving signals. Below I attached error:

```
[Novo_Comp5-PC:09596] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in
file /pub/devel/openmpi/openmpi-1.7.2-1/src/openmpi-1.7.2/orte/mca/ess/hnp/ess_hnp_module.c
at line 270
```

It looks like `orte_init` failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during `orte_init`; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

```
  orte_plm_base_select failed
  --> Returned value Not found (-13) instead of ORTE_SUCCES
```

Comment: Can you upload a small test program and the error it gives. Otherwise we can sit here all day and guess what your problem might be.

Comment: As there are multiple cpp files and I compiled them using make command where it showed no error so I added error report to my post for more clarification which comes when I run this program

Comment: This still isn't helpful, sorry. In doing a quick google search with this error, there are a lot of [references](http://www.neff.co.at/2013/12/27/Open-MPI-with-Cygwin.html) to having to install `rsh` or `ssh`. Have you got that installed? Or have you got a hostfile (or command line option) with either `localhost` or actual hosts to run on?